# Sorting Updated Columns In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello good day everyone.

I have a table design in SQL server that looks like this:

```
NAME     AGE       WORK         BIRTH
TEST     21        NONE         12/12/2000
```

In this table, I have created a trigger upon updating table and would save the data to audit log table. This audit log table holds the value being updated and the columns that has been update. I have a query snippet here that gets the columns that has been updated. I also get this query her on stack.

```
DECLARE @idTable INT
SELECT  @idTable = T.id 
FROM    sysobjects P JOIN sysobjects T ON P.parent_obj = T.id 
WHERE   P.id = @@procid

-- Get COLUMNS_UPDATED if update
--
DECLARE @Columns_Updated VARCHAR(50)


SELECT  @Columns_Updated =  ISNULL(@Columns_Updated + ', ', '') + name 
FROM    syscolumns 
WHERE   id = @idTable   
AND     CONVERT(VARBINARY,REVERSE(COLUMNS_UPDATED())) & POWER(CONVERT(BIGINT, 2), colorder - 1) > 0
```

Now my audit log table looks like this:

```
OLD             NEW                 COLUMNS_UPDATED
tEST,21,NONE    TEST2,20,TEACHER    AGE,NAME,WORK
```

Now my problem is, how I can sort the columns updated that looks like also the design table. My preferred output should look like this.

```
OLD             NEW                 COLUMNS_UPDATED
tEST,21,NONE    TEST2,20,TEACHER    NAME,AGE,WORK
```

I hope anyone could help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```